# Has the First Posts review limit recently changed?

Tags: support, review

**I reviewed 27 First Posts today:**
[image]

**Then I got a message thanking me for reviewing 20 posts:**
[image]

**And the Stats page indicates I've only reviewed 20 items:**
[image]

**What's going on here?**

Comment: I am pretty sure this belongs on meta.stackexchange.com instead of here.  Any limits would be something SE can answer.   My guess is a few of those questions were eventually deleted though.

Comment: Sorry...changed the question a bit.  But aren't limits set per SE site, not for the network as a whole?

Comment: The limits might be.  If you were able to review past the limit then it is a bug and thus should be reported as such.

Comment: OK.  If someone can confirm this shouldn't have been possible I'll request a migration of the question.

Comment: The stats page shows you as having only reviewed 20 items. http://superuser.com/review/first-posts/stats

Comment: @Ramhound I confirmed all but 2 of my reviewed items are something other than deleted.  (The two items shown in black text in my screenshot appear to have been deleted).  That least 25 items.

Comment: @Mokubai So do you think this is a bug?

Comment: I can see 20 in the last 16 hours, and then more 18 hours ago. I suspect that you were reviewing either side of the daily cut-off and 5 of those were yesterday.  I can't remember exactly when the review period starts.

Comment: @Mokubai That has to be it.  I must have reviewed those just a hair after the cutoff time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see 20 in the last 16 hours, and then more 18 hours ago. I suspect that you were reviewing either side of the daily cut-off and 5 of those were yesterday.

I can't remember exactly when the review period starts, but I suspect it is at 00:00 GMT and is not a rolling "day" and instead your limit is reset daily.

Comment: I know for a fact you're correct that the cut off is 0:00 GMT.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely it, your reviews that were 18 hours ago show as "2015-08-20 23:43:46Z" when you hover your mouse over them, and the ones 16 hours ago show as "2015-08-21 01:48:27Z" and the Z would be Zulu time. So the reset is almost certainly daily at 00:00:00 Zulu / GMT.

Comment: I didn't know you could get the exact time by hovering!  **That** should be the answer! Had I known that I wouldn't have needed to post.  :p

Comment: @Twisty: That works anywhere you see a time field expressed imprecisely (e.g., "11 mins ago", "15 hours ago", "yesterday", etc.), such as when a question or answer was posted or edited (including in the revision history), when a comment was posted, or even when a user joined or was last active ("Member for 2 years", "Last seen 3 hours ago" in the user profile).  In fact, *all* events that are recorded in the revision history (including close, reopen, lock, migrate, etc.)